# База данных соц сети

Tags: база-данных

Хочу написать свое веб-приложение. Раньше никогда не занимался проектированием БД. Прошу оценить и указать мои ошибки. Идея такая

Пользователи могут создавать альбомы и могут добавлять фотографии. Так же пользователи могут подружиться и обмениваться сообщениями. Еще у каждой фотографии можно добавлять хэштеги. Их решил сохранять прям в таблице с фотографиями. Еще возник вопрос. как лучше хранить сами картинки? Сохранять их на серваке и в БД помещать путь до файла, или лучше хранить прям изображение в БД?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UDP Обновил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В таблицах friends, users_to_roles и им подобных собственный id записи не нужен, включайте оба значимых поля в parimary key и все. Заодно уникальность записи обеспечите, что бы user1 не мог быть другом user2 дважды. Картинки ... Я бы отдельно хранил и в базе пути или вообще только некий id по которому потом путь вычисляется. Так будет проще картинки разложить на несколько серверов и отдавать быстро ngix без использования базы

Comment: `messages_to_photos` - как фотография может прочитать ваше сообщение? Может все-таки комментарии? И не совсем ясно с вашими диалогами и сообщениями - как это работать должно? И зачем `messages_to_photos`, если можно сразу внести `photo_id` в `messages` Не совсем понятно зачем все эти таблицы нужны (возможно, из-за неудачных названий). Если dialog - это общение нескольких людей, то как определить кому принадлежит сообщение? Если это только один человек - то почему диалог? И почему бы тогда не внести `user_id` в `dialogs`?

Comment: "что бы user1 не мог быть другом user2 дважды" - `user1, user2` и `user2, user1`

Comment: @Igor, проверять-то можно только по первому полю, тогда такие записи будут нормально обрабатываться + отсутствие второй записи может означать, например, "подписку" (как в вк) + кластеризация так лучше отработает

Comment: @Igor `user1, user2` и `user2, user1` - это нормальная ситуация. Одной из записей может не быть, если только user1 добавил user2, но не на оборот. А вот допускать две записи `user1, user2` и `user1, user2` точно нельзя

Comment: @BOPOH если добавить `photo_id` в `message` то как быть если фото не будет в сообщении? или если будет много фотографий в одном сообщении? тож самое и в таблице `dialogs`. `user_to_dialogs` и `messages_to_photos` это связующие таблицы

Comment: @MrGarison, ну я и говорю - не совсем понятно что вы хотели сделать. Лучше бы еще словами описали как эти таблицы связаны. Если фотографию можно в сообщение добавить - тогда да, вносить это не надо. Мой комент относился к случаю, когда "сообщение" было комментом к фотографии. Если users_to_dialogs - это связующая таблица, то как определить кто сообщение написал? А если фотография не добавлена ни в один альбом - как определить какому пользователю она принадлежит?

Comment: в photos есть поле tag, а если еще отдельно таблица тегов - это разные данные, просто названы одинаково? или вы просто забыли удалить tag из photos?

Comment: @BOPOH tag хотел сначала хранить в таблице фото, потом решил сделать отдельную таблицу, забыл удалить. В таблицу message добавил user_id, чтоб было ясно кто написал сообщение. Если пользователь будет отправлять картинки в сообщениях, то будет создаваться какой-нибудь стаднартный альбом, где будут храниться картинки переданные в сообщениях.

Comment: Убедительная просьба **не вносить изменения в суть вопроса**, в данном случае суть это ошибки в **конкретной структуре БД**. Оставьте какую-то одну. Сейчас ответов ещё нет, но если бы они были, их авторы попали бы в *неоднозначную* ситуацию.

Answer (score 1):

Касательно того, где хранить фотографии, то однозначно на сервере!
Выкиньте из головы даже теоретическую возможность пихать блобы в БД!

Я недавно переделывал класс загрузчика на gd и систему хранения файлов (картинок), и остановился на таком варианте.

В СУБД (MariaDB) я храню тип файла (раширение) в поле ENUM.
Если связь один 1 к 1, то это просто поле `img ENUM('jpg','png','gif'),`.
Если связь 1 ко многим, то таблица.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_goods_img`
(
    `gid` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `order` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `img` ENUM('jpg','png','gif') NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`gid`,`order`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Основная моя идея в том, что название файла у меня состоит из id-шников, разделителя и точкой с расширением. Например `13.jpg` или `6-2.png`, где 13 - это, `id` соответствующего поля поля в этой таблице, или 6 - это `gid`, а 2 - это `order` соответствующего поля ранее приведенной таблицы.

В таком случае наличие `img` отличного от `NULL` нам указывает на существование файла и его тип, а имя файла вычисляется динамически и оно предсказуемо.

```
SELECT *,CONCAT(`id`,'.',`img`)`img` FROM `tbl_user`;
SELECT `gid`,`order`,CONCAT(`gid`,'-',`order`,'.',`img`)`img` FROM `tbl_goods_img`;
```

И подобные запросы сразу нам выдают полное имя картинки в поле `img`, причём если оно отсутствует, (img IS NULL) то CONCAT, и соответственно, `img` вернёт тоже `NULL`.

Это, в целом, позволяет по минимуму выделять память в БД для хранения картинок, полное безразличие к пользовательскому имени картинки, информативное и ожидаемое имя картинки.